# Grouping non null fields together in Kibana

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4

Given the following three `User` entries in an ElasticSearch index:

```
"user": [
   {
      "userId": "100",
      "hobby": "chess"
   }

"user": [
   {
      "userId": "200",
      "hobby": "music"
   }

"user": [
   {
      "userId": "300",
      "hobby": ""
   }
```

I want to create a vertical bar chart to compare the number of users who have a hobby as opposed to those who do not. Individual hobbies should not be shown separately, but grouped together.

If split along the Y axis, one block would take up two thirds of the height (the two users with hobbies) and one block one third of the height (the one user with no hobbies).

How could one achieve this grouping in Kibana?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to choose `Split Bars` and then `Filters` aggregation.  Once you have that selected you should see `Query 1` with `*` in it.  Change the `*` to `hobby:*`.  Next hit `Add Filter` and put in `NOT hobby:*`

The filters aggregation lets you bucket things pretty much any way you can search for things.